# How to update the contents of a dropdown when file uploaded in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular8

Currently I have a dropdown. I will upload a csv. I want the contents of the dropdown to be the header (the first row) of the uploaded csv. But when I implement this, the dropdown list is not updated.
It is only updated once I upload another csv. That is, if file1 has header list headers1, and file2 has headers list headers2, if I upload file1 there is no update to the dropdown, then I upload file2, then the dropdown shows the contents of headers1.
Code:

HTML

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event.target)" name="myfile"/>
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let option of headers">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'cross-tab';
    csvContent: string;
    parsedCsv: string[][];
    headers: string[];

    ngOnInit(){
    }

    onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
        const csvSeparator = ",";
        const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;
        // alert(this.csvContent);

        const txt = textFromFileLoaded;
        const csv = [];
        const lines = txt.split('\n');
        lines.forEach(element => {
            const cols: string[] = element.split(csvSeparator);
            csv.push(cols);
            });
        this.parsedCsv = csv;
        //this.headers = this.parsedCsv[0];
        //console.log(this.parsedCsv);
    }

    onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        const files = input.files;
        var content = this.csvContent;

        if(files && files.length)
        {
            const fileToRead = files[0];
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad.bind(this);
            fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
            //this.headers = ["A", "B", "C"];
            this.headers = this.parsedCsv[0];
            console.log(this.parsedCsv);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onFileLoad` method is actually executed after `onFileSelect`, so when you try to do this

`this.headers = this.parsedCsv[0];`

`this.parsedCsv` is empty and it makes an error that prevent compiler to continue.

Please try the code below, it worked for me

```
  onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
      const csvSeparator = ",";
      const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;    
      const txt = textFromFileLoaded;
      const csv = [];
      const lines = txt.split('\n');
      lines.forEach(element => {
          const cols: string[] = element.split(csvSeparator);
          csv.push(cols);
          });
          this.headers = csv[0];
  }

  onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
      const files = input.files;
      var content = this.csvContent;

      if(files && files.length)
      {
          const fileToRead = files[0];
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad.bind(this);
          fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
      }
  }
```